# Setting a project as the main project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

Can any body tell me how to set a java project as the debugging main project in eclipse IDE.It always can't run the newly coded project because of another existing  one is trying to run. Is there any option like "set as main project" option in netbeans
Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "main project". Do you want to run that project by default if you hit the run button?

Comment: @André exactly that is what I want, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I know what you are asking, so I am taking a bit of a guess.  Under Eclipse "Preferences", you can go to "Run/Debug-->Launching".  In there at the bottom there is a section called "Launch Operation" that gives you some control over what Eclipse launches.

This may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I resolved the problem dude. It was a problem with my jboss server[configuration](https://community.jboss.org/message/200617) hope this will be helpful to you also.Thanks